# Error connecting to IMAP server: localhost. 111 : Connection refused

Tags: php

> Error connecting to IMAP server: localhost. 111 : Connection refused

Also when I try to telnet imap I receive the following error:

```
telnet localhost 143

Trying ::1...

Trying 127.0.0.1...

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: what are you using, on your local machine, as an imap server?

Comment: Are you asking whether I am using ubuntu or redhat

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: We will be doing some configurations in dovecot.conf file and named.conf.local. This editing is done using html